# Suddenly unable to import pandas_market_calendars

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, import

I have been running the same python script daily for some months & have not edited it recently.
As of today the import

```
import pandas_market_calendars as market_calendars
```

Fails with error in the file:

<>\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py
 register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

The offending lines of pkg_resources.py are:

```
register_loader_type(type(None), DefaultProvider)
if importlib_bootstrap is not None:
   register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
```

Is there a work-around please?

Comment: I'd guess that your Python/pip installation is corrupt in some way.

Comment: Probably something like that yes thank you - I copied the files and directory structure and set up a new project - which works fine although it does not fix the problem